# Faker with Laravel taking appending data from another factory

Tags: laravel, seeding, faker, laravel-seeding

```
$factory->define(App\Client::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    $company_name = $faker->Company;

    return [
        'name' => $company_name,
        'short_name' => substr($company_name, 0, 3),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});



$factory->define(App\Campaign::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'unique_id' => $faker->numerify('ABC###'),
        'client' => function() {
            return factory('App\Client')->create()->id;
        }

    ];
});
```

I am generating come clients and campaigns. One client can have many campaigns

How do I take the **short_name** from the Company and pass it to a the campaign class so I can append it to a random string to create a unique id in the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You don't need to use an anonymous function in the campaign class, you can just reference the `factory` directly. Use a variable inside the Campaign factory and just reference whatever values you need.

```
$factory->define(App\Campaign::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $client = factory(App\Client::class)->create();

    return [
        'unique_id' => $faker->numerify('ABC###') . $client->short_name,
        'client' => $client->id

    ];
});
```